# Trouble Re-mapping keyboard on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, configuration, keyboard, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have Raspbian Debian Wheezy installed on my Raspberry Pi. I was trying to learn python in IDLE 3 but when I tried to type the Number symbol (aka Hashtag, Pound) it came out with "£", so I can't type the number symbol at all. Also this symbol " is now swapped with the @. I was trying to reconfigure my keyboard with "sudo raspi-config" but I don't know what my model for my keyboard is. I am not familiar with the logo. But in the back it says "98149 Multimedia Keyboard". Is there a way to remap my keyboard correctly?

P.S. The default selected model is Generic 105 key (Intl) PC

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command

```
setxkbmap us
```

Comment: Or with the gui, something like `Generic <10x>-key (US)`